# What files are needed for a release build with Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, build, qmake

I compiled the standard qt widget project (Desktop Qt 5.4.0 MSVC2013 32 bit) as a release build with QtCreator 3.3.0  on Windows 7 32 bit and put the qt libraries in the same folder (Qt5Core.dll, Qt5Gui.dll, icudt53,dll, icuin53.dll, icuuc53.dll)
And when I start the program the error (roughly translated) "... doesn't work anymore" appears.

When I do the same thing with the debug release and put the appropriate debug libaries in the folder it works.

What do I have to make differently with the release build?

Thanks in advance for any help!

A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to deploy your application using [The Windows Deployment Tool](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool) which could be found in `QTDIR/bin/windeployqt.exe`. It automatically puts all necessary files in your application directory.

Open your command prompt and add the path to your Qt directory and it's `bin` folder to the `PATH` variable like :

```
set PATH= path\to\Qt\bin
```

Next run the windows deployment tool with your application path as the argument:

```
windeployqt.exe  <path-to-app-binary>
```

This way you make sure that the deployed application would work on any computer and you have included whatever necessary.

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked. But the strange thing is: Now it runs with the same dlls it didnt run with before. Obviously windeployqt  has changed my binary in some way.